# k - NN classifier vs logistic regression for the MNIST data set

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, k-nearest-neighbour

What would be the difference between using a k-NN classifier and logistic regression for the MNIST data set (large database of handwritten digits)?

Edit: I used both methods in python (built-in functions in sklearn). I used iterations to find the k that gave the greatest accuracy. 
It turned out that k-NN achieved greater accuracy than Logistic Regression. However, I'm not sure as to which method is better in terms of speed, what would be a good method to analyze this?

Comment: What kind of difference are you asking for? Speed? Accuracy? Data pre-processing? These are entirely different classification algorithms! Downvoting because 1) it is not clear what you are asking, 2) the question does not demonstrate any effort made by yourself.

Comment: @JanKukacka Sorry about that, I updated the question. Please let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I removed the downvote. See my answer below. Also, I think you are messing together linear and logistic regression.

Comment: I also downvote this question because OP can spend more time on reading what are these two methods in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k-NN classifier is much faster to train (because it does not really involve any training) than logistic regression, but much its predictions are much slower. The reason for this is the way k-NN works: For a new sample (in your case a 28x28 grayscale image) it needs to compute a distance to all samples in the training set. As you can see, the complexity of this depends on 1) size of the training set (60000 for MNIST), and 2) number of dimensions (784 for MNIST).

You can easily check this in Python by wrapping your functions into the following code:

```
import time as t
...

t_start = t.clock()
for i in xrange(50):
    # predict a sample using k-nn
t_end = t.clock()
print 'k-nn needs {}s for prediction of 1 sample'.format((t_end-t_start)/50)

t_start = t.clock()
for i in xrange(50):
    # predict a sample using logistic regression
t_end = t.clock()
print 'logistic regression needs {}s for prediction of 1 sample'.format((t_end-t_start)/50)
```